# What is the right way to allot a distinct value to an agent's parameter in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I want my agent to be of a single type. Where type contains a list of 3 options. And the allotment should be based on probability. E.g. let's say I want to allot 1: 30%, 2: 50% and 3: 20% to each of the agents generated in the source of my main tab.

I tried with one of the ways by declaring th parameter as int and then writing randomTrue(0.3)?1:randomTrue(0.7)?2:3 in the default value. But every time the agent comes with the same value of 2.

Please can anyone help me with this??

And if I try to allot the parameters in the main window at any of the blocks, do they get attached to the specific agent that passes through that block or its value just gets updated for that time until the other agent passes? Actually I have to check each and every agent for the parameter and then send it through a specific output path from the selectoutput block.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not actually change anything in the created agent.

Create a parameter `myType´ of type Integer.

In your source code write:
`agent.myType = randomTrue(0.3) ? 0 : randomTrue(0.7) ? 1 : 2`

Make sure your Source block actually creates agents of the Agent type that holds the `myType` parameter.

Study some of the example models and tutorials, it is covered in many places :-)

Comment: Thanks I will try that, is it also possible to allot the value in the main by sending the agent through different selectoutput block based on the probabilities and then write agent.myType = 1 or 2 or 3 depending upon the block it went to.

Comment: Sure, almost anything is possible in AnyLogic (its in the name ;-) ). Feel free to open a clear new question if you get stuck (but always try yourself first ;-) ).

Comment: If the parameter is in your agent, then what you describe in your original post should work.  Can you please clarify how your original problem was set up?  The only way I can think of it not working is if you had overridden the default somewhere.  I was going to add some notes about set_parameter versus parameter equals, but I am puzzled why what you have written doesn't work.